# how to append and image echoed in another page

Tags: php, jquery

I am using a form plugin (jQuery form plugin to be exact) and I want to know how to append the data echoed in the processing page the file I want to append is an image file.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = { 
        target:'.prof_img',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        url:'upload_profile_pic.php',
        type:'POST', 
        success:function() { 
            $("#theater_outer").hide();
            $('a[class="prof_img"]').empty(); //where prof_img is the div i want to empty and append the image inside
            $('a[class="prof_img"]').append(data);
        } 
    };      
    $('#upload_profile_photo').ajaxForm(options); 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the data param in the `success` callback `function`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var options = { 
         target:'.prof_img',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
         url:'upload_profile_pic.php',
         type:'POST', 
         success:function(data) { 
             $("#theater_outer").hide();
             $('a[class="prof_img"]').empty(); //where prof_img is the div i want to empty and append the image inside
             $('a.prof_img').append($(data));
         } 
     };      
     $('#upload_profile_photo').ajaxForm(options); 
 });
```

Comment: im not shure i follow you

Comment: When you run the script now, what does `data` look like when it is appended to you link?

Comment: nothing gets appended.basically what i want to do is clear the image within prof_image ad append it with the image which is echoed in the procesor file

Comment: What we need to know is what data your `upload_profile_pic.php` prints. If it simply does `echo $someImage` where `$someImage` is a binary then you would want `echo base64_encode($someImage)` to take the approach i propose.

Comment: it echoes the image tag with the src

Comment: then you want `$('a[class="prof_img"]').append($(data));`

Comment: nope does not work will echoing the src and then replace the src would work?

Comment: can you paste exactly what is appended to `$('a[class="prof_img"]')` currently?

Comment: like i said **NOTHING** i want to append a img echoed in another page

Comment: it echoes <img src="$location"> where the $location is the location of the img

Comment: you forgot the `data` param in `success:function(data) {`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = { 
        target:'.prof_img',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        url:'upload_profile_pic.php',
        type:'POST', 
        success:function(img) { //img should be the server side response
            $("#theater_outer").hide();
            $('a.prof_img').html(img); //replace inner html with the image html
              //^ simpler class based selector
        } 
    };      
    $('#upload_profile_photo').ajaxForm(options); 
});
```